# Powershell query registry subkeys and return only specified key name and data field

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell command that will return the value of specific keys in the registry. The name of the keys are "Name" "Data" and "Percentage"

What I have below grabs all the subkeys, but I can't figure out how to just select the names of the keys above and have them outputted to me? It seems like it would be easy, but I can't figure out how to have *multiple* results in one query. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Get-ChildItem hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Software\Softwarename | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using '\*' with Get-ItemProperty cmdlet.for example

```
Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Get-ChildItem hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Software\Softwarename | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Data" -or $_.Name -eq "Name" -or $_.Name -eq "Percentage" } | ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath }
```

Comment: I get an error message saying "Get-ItemProperty : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." If I switch things around to this: Get-ChildItem hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Software\Softwarename ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Data" -or $_.Name -eq "Name" -or $_.Name -eq "Percentage" } I don't get an error message but nothing shows up

Comment: Try now, if it doesn't work then try without selecting property first